# How could I mention a user in an embed?

Tags: discord, discord.js, embed

I'm currently having an issue where I'm unable to ping people in embeds. I've searched up solutions online, but none of them are working. Here's my code, thanks.

```js
else if (command === 'post') {
        if (!message.member) return;

        const messageContent = args.slice(1).join(' ');
        if (!messageContent) return await message.channel.send("Invalid syntax, please include full detail, including what you need done, payment, time etc.");
        
        await message.channel.send("Post sent for approval.");

        const hiringEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(embedColor)
        .setTitle('Hiring post.')
        .setAuthor({name : message.member.user.username, iconURL : message.member.user.displayAvatarURL()})
        .setDescription(messageContent)
        .setFooter({text : `Post by <@${message.member.user.id}>`}) // This is the line that wont work
        .setTimestamp()

        await client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === '937027971137548378').send({embeds : [hiringEmbed]});
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you can mention people in embed footers

Answer (score 1):

To ping someone you need to add the user to the content of the message you send `channel.send({content:'<@${id}>', embeds: [hiringEmbed]`

Answer (score 0):

```
.setFooter({text : `Post by ${message.author.tag}`})
```

or

```
.setFooter(`Post by ${message.author.tag}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot ping a member in an embed but rather only mention them. So, you need to ping them in the regular content of the message instead of the embed.

```
await client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === '937027971137548378').send({content: `${message.member.user.id}`, embeds : [hiringEmbed]});
```

In the footer you can use their username instead if you want to mention who used the command.